# JS - check if array does not have any value but a specified value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array that can contain many values. What I need is a way to check if all values in this array match my desired value.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
const arr = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'];
// I need to see if all values in arr is eqaul to 'foo'
const mappedArr = arr.map(item => item === 'foo');
if (!mappedArr.includes(false)) {
  console.log('my condition is satisfied');
} else {
  console.log('Nope! something else is in there');
}
```

But this requires looping over all elements and converting the array into a "true / false" array and checking the new array for including a value.

Which does not seem to be a good approach in case of large lists. It would be much better if I was able to break this loop as soon as I met the first not matching element.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would someone write such complex logic when there is [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)?

```js
const arr1 = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'];
const arr2 = ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'];

const checker = (arr, str) => arr.every(s => s === str);

console.log(checker(arr1, 'foo'));
console.log(checker(arr2, 'foo'));
```

Comment: @SalmanA `every()` will return `false` as soon as it will found an element that will not match the criteria set by callback.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter instead of map

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'];
arr.filter(e=>e=='foo').length==arr.length?console.log(true):console.log(false)
```

Comment: cool way but i think this method loops over all elements too.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Array.prototype.some`

```
arr.some(element => element !== 'foo') !== false
```

It will returns true if one of the elements isn't equal to `'foo'`,
false if they all equals to `'foo'`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
let arr = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'];
console.log(arr.every(elm => elm === 'foo')); //false

arr = arr.map(elm => 'foo'); //changing every element to 'foo' for testing
console.log(arr.every(elm => elm === 'foo')); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the map does. The map function return the array of returned values. use every - `The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function`. You are returning the boolean value item === 'foo' and so you are getting the array of booleans.